# Make USB flash drive appear to host as an external hard disk

Tags: usb, partitioning

I have recently purchased a large 256GB USB flash drive and I’m planning on partitioning this as such:

1. Linux Multiboot Partition (using XBoot or YUMI).
2. Windows Installer Partition.
3. Any and all data (i.e. just storage).

However, for whatever reason, Windows won’t recognise any partition except the primary or first logical partition on a USB flash drive. Consequently, is it possible to modify my USB flash drive such that it appears to all computers as an external hard disk?

I understand that it is possible to do on a single machine by editting the driver [as explained here](http://www.getusb.info/usb-hack-turn-a-usb-stick-into-a-hard-drive-or-local-disk/).

However, this won’t help if I want to be able to use it anywhere. I would need to modify something on the USB flash drive itself.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you put the windows-must-see stuff in the first partition it should satisfy windows' weird quirk, and still let you boot linux from a remaining partition, grub can go anywhere but I don't know how xboot or yumi work exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lot of USB flash drives [this Lexar USB tool (Lexar’s BootIt ) *might* work](http://www.getusb.info/downloads/lexar_usb_tool.zip). It flips a bit on the USB flash drive which identifies to the host whether or not it is removable device.

However, while this works for some USB flash drives, there are no guarantees as to whether or not it will work for any particular model. It worked for me.

Comment: The linked "Lexar tool" from the getusb.info link in the Q is at least 9 years old and about WinXP, does it even still work for anything still supported? What did you use it on?

Comment: @Xen2050 to my surprise it worked on Windows 10 for my Patriot Supersonic Rage 2 USB stick, which is a pretty high-end, expensive drive